# How do elves, or other long lived races, act when confronted with much more potent members of the short-lived races?

Tags: dnd-5e, roleplaying, elf

Example situations:

1. An adventuring party at the 3rd tier, mostly made of humans in their 20s, and plenty of raw power at their disposal. The Elves are interacting with dangerous individuals several centuries their junior, yet far more power. How do Elves act in such a situation?
2. NPCs who an adventuring party might want to take on as 'help'. An elf with 100+ years of help being the assistant researcher to a human in their early 20s?

To clarify: Elves and Long lived races tend to view younger races as rushed and brash. But when that brashness ends up with powerful characters, how would the long-living races act and treat such people?

A lot of advice seems to talk about elven pride, but being needlessly snobby towards a group that could easily wipe out the village doesn’t seem realistic, simply based on self-preservation. There is a lot of discussion about how long-lived races get to the state where they (mechanically) are on parity with others of much shorter lifespans. But when that shifts from parity to overwhelming favour of the short-lived race, what happens?

Comment: This question, [With the lifespan of elves, would you ever encounter a low-level elf?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55274/62294) might be a duplicate, if not, it’s really close. That said “how would you do this” is somewhat opinion based, I’m not sure it’s a good fit for the stack.

Comment: Let me rephrase it then: How do elves react when when confronted with much more potent members of the short-lived races?

I saw that other question. It's not that I'm unsure about elven powers, its about how elves, with their relatively isolated and distinct society, react to perceived "young races" rocking around with significant firepower. Whether or not they think the Humans are crude, the interaction with a group with undeniable physical power is what I'm querying.

Comment: I think that’s a better question framing. This seems like a good question, albeit probably a very difficult question.

Comment: "How do NPCs of race X react to phenomenon Y" might have an objective answer written somewhere - perhaps in that race's entry in the monster manual, a supplement that describes them, or a campaign setting source book. As such, I won't vote to close this question - but it's entirely possible the answer will turn out to be "the rules don't say, so it's up to the GM."

Comment: I've read the VGM entry on elves. It gives a lot of details on general interactions, but interactions where the power imbalance is tilted in the short-lived races' favour is lacking.

Comment: If the elves are snobby enough, this could easily be answered by thinking what humans would do if a tribe of chimps with assault rifles showed up to visit.